# How do I auto-refresh a JWT in redux without breaking async flow?

Tags: javascript, redux, jwt, refresh-token, redux-middleware

## High-level description

I have a React/redux/electron app that uses Google Oauth. I want to be able to refresh the access token automatically when it expires. I've researched this and solved it semi-successfully using middleware, but my solution is erroring in certain situations.

I've implemented a refresh middleware that runs on every API action. It checks whether the access token is expired or about to expire. If so, instead of dispatching the action it received, it dispatches a token refresh action and queues up any other actions until a new access token is received. After that, it dispatches all actions in its queue.

However, one of my action creators looks something like this:

```
function queryThreads(params) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const threads = await dispatch(fetchThreads(params))
    const newPageToken = threads.payload.nextPageToken
  }
}
```

When the refresh middleware doesn't run because the token isn't expiring, `threads.payload` will be defined here and everything will work as intended.

However, when the refresh middleware does run, `threads.payload` will be `undefined` because the `dispatch` seems to resolve with the value of the token refresh action, rather than the `fetchThreads` action.

How do I ensure that the token gets refreshed (and updated in `state`/`localStorage`), `fetchThreads` gets dispatched with the updated token, and the `threads` variable gets assigned to the resolved value of the correct Promise?

## Links to Project Code

[This is my refresh middleware](https://github.com/stevengoldberg/threadcount/blob/master/app/middleware/refresh-middleware.js). It was inspired by [this article](https://medium.com/@viewflow/full-stack-django-quick-start-with-jwt-auth-and-react-redux-part-iii-873584a65119) by [kmmbvnr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46548/kmmbvnr).

[This is the token refresh action creator](https://github.com/stevengoldberg/threadcount/blob/master/app/actions/auth.js#L117-L145).

[This is the line in my queryThreads action creator](https://github.com/stevengoldberg/threadcount/blob/master/app/actions/threads.js#L26) that throws when the token has to refresh (`threads.payload` is `undefined`).

[This is the reducer where I update state](https://github.com/stevengoldberg/threadcount/blob/master/app/reducers/auth.js#L20-L27) in response to a token refresh.

[This is the middleware where I update localStorage](https://github.com/stevengoldberg/threadcount/blob/master/app/middleware/storage.js#L30-L40) in response to a token refresh.

Comment: why don't you use localStorage for it ? Browser refresh will lose redux state

Comment: I am already storing tokens in localStorage.

Comment: I gave an implementation to someone on SO, which I had implemented on my project as well. It has different approaches to refresh token. If you want I’d give an answer below with my answer link. So if it helps you other users can also leverage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I've solved the issue by rewriting the refresh middleware like this:

```
function createRefreshMiddleware() {
  const postponedRSAAs = [];
  return ({ dispatch, getState }) => {
    const rsaaMiddleware = apiMiddleware({ dispatch, getState });
    return next => action => {
      if (isRSAA(action)) {
        try {
          const auth = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth'));
          const { refresh_token: refreshToken } = auth;
          const expirationTime = jwtDecode(auth.id_token).exp * 1000;
          const isAccessTokenExpiring =
            moment(expirationTime) - moment() < 300000;

          if (refreshToken && isAccessTokenExpiring) {
            postponedRSAAs.push(action);
            if (postponedRSAAs.length === 1) {
              return rsaaMiddleware(next)(
                dispatch(() => attemptTokenRefresh(refreshToken))
              ).then(() => {
                const postponedRSAA = postponedRSAAs.pop();
                return dispatch(postponedRSAA);
              });
            }
            return rsaaMiddleware(next)(action);
          }
          return rsaaMiddleware(next)(action);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
          return next(action);
        }
      }
      return next(action);
    };
  };
}

export default createRefreshMiddleware();
```

Now the postponed action will always be chained off of the token refresh action, so we don't have the problem of the original promise resolving with the wrong value; plus it's more concise.